# Get view from ListView row

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

Basically all I'm trying to do is have a button appear in a row, when the row is selected. I have tried many methods, and they all seem to work including the one below...I get the `ImageView` but calling `setVisibility()` on it does nothing:

**ListFragment**

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
    setSellButton();
}

public View getViewForPosition(int position){
    int relativePos = position - listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    if( relativePos < 0 || relativePos > listview.getChildCount()){
        return null;
    }
    return listview.getChildAt(relativePos);
}

public void setSellButton() {
    View x = getViewForPosition(Constants.lastSelection);
    ImageView y = (ImageView)x.findViewById(R.id.ivSell);
    y.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

No errors, and debug shows that everything is right in `setSellButton()` but `setVisibility()` never works. Is this something I can only do in the adapter? Thanks!

Edit: **Row Layout XML as requested**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/thelist"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ivStar"
        android:src="@drawable/liststar"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="10">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold">
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvValue"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

</LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/coin"
        android:id="@+id/ivSell"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Edit: **Adapter**

```
public class InventoryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {

    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<String> names;
    private final ArrayList<Integer> stock;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    View rowView;
    String stockText;
    TextView textView;
    TextView textView2;
    ImageView iv;

    public InventoryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<Integer> stock) {
        super(context, R.layout.inv_rowlayout, stock);
        this.context = context;
        this.names = names;
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inv_rowlayout, parent, false);

        String stockNumber = stock.get(position).toString();
        final String name = names.get(position);

        textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        textView.setText(names.get(position));
        textView2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvValue);
        textView2.setText(stockNumber);
        iv = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.ivSell);

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Wait. You want to show the `Button` on the row, or on another part of your layout? Could you post your `xml` too please?

Comment: @Mauker added to question.

Comment: Try my answer sir. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. First of all allow me to adapt your row xml. It's better to use `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`. It's more flexible.

**row_layout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="@drawable/thelist"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/listView_minHeight">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ivStar"
        android:contentDescription="@string/list_item_image_desc"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/liststar" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivStar"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ivStar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:id="@+id/tvValue"
        android:layout_below="@+id/label"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivStar"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ivStar"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ivSell"
        android:src="@drawable/coin"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You're probably subclassing `BaseAdapter`. What you'll have to do is to create a method there to change the visibility of your `ImageView`. Then when you have your item clicked, you can get the `adapter` and call that method.

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context_;
    private ArrayList<YourDataHolder> items;
    private YourDataHolder lastHolder = null;

    private final String LOG_TAG = CustomAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<YourDataHolder> items) {
        this.context_ = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return items.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context_.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
        }

        final TextView tv_label = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        final TextView tv_value = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvValue);
        final ImageView iv_star = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivSell);

        YourDataHolder holder = items.get(position);

        tv_label.setText(holder.getLabel());
        tv_value.setText(holder.getValue());

        if (holder.isImageVisible() && iv_star.getVisibility() == ImageView.INVISIBLE) {
            iv_star.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
        }
        else if (iv_star.getVisibility() == ImageView.VISIBLE) {
            iv_star.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
        }


        return convertView;
    }

    public void onItemSelect(int position) {
        if (position < items.size()) {
            YourDataHolder holder = items.get(position);

            holder.setVisibility(true);

            if (lastHolder != null) {
                lastHolder.setVisibility(false);
            }

            lastHolder = holder;
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming you're using a data holder like this one:

**YourDataHolder.java**

```
public class YourDataHolder {
    private String label;
    private String value;
    private boolean isVisible;

    public YourDataHolder(String label, String value) {
        this.label = label;
        this.value = value;
        isVisible = false;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public boolean getVisibility() {
        return isVisible;
    }

    public void setVisibility(boolean isVisible) {
        this.isVisible = isVisible;
    }
}
```

And then, on your `onItemClick()`, do the magic.

**YourFragment.java**

```
private CustomAdapter adapter;

// Rest of the Fragment. Where you create the adapter, and assign it to the ListView.

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
    adapter.onItemSelect(position);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I tried to implement this but had no luck due to issues from sending lists that are not in YourDataHolder (this is all new to me). I am still working on it and trying to understand it more and make it work, just wanted to thank you for the input. Also, I'm extending `ArrayAdapter<Integer>` instead of `BaseAdapter` for my CustomAdapter

Comment: It will work with either one of those adapters. If you are still having some trouble. I can try to help

Comment: I'm calling adapter like:

adapter = new InventoryAdapter(getActivity(), listNames, listMyStock);

where `listNames` is `ArrayList<String>`

Answer (score 1):

My guess is, that after the click on the item you need to call the notifyDataSetChanged method on the adapter. And then render the button on the selected list view item.

Comment: I did try calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter, and that didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Could you please post your adapter code? After calling notifyDataSetChanged the adapters getView() method should be called. Can you confirm that?

Answer (score 0):

It is something that I would do in the adapter, having direct access to the imageview would make the process easier. I previously attempted to do it from the listview level and was unable to do to the conditions I had setup.